# Invoking an action of an Intent Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, adb, intentfilter

I just created a new intentService app in Android Studio and i'm a bit confused as to how to invoke it.

Is it only meant for invocation from another app explicitly?
Can't i declare an intent filter in the manifest and then have it respond to broadcast intents?

For example,
I have an intent filter set up like so

```
<service
        android:name=".RemoteShopKeyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.srini.remoteshopservice.action.FOO" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

And within the Main service class I handle the intent. However how do I invoke the service with an action other than android.intent.action.MAIN via the adb?

I start the service using adb shell am startservice

Comment: can you elaborate please? what should i give -n?

Comment: I'm currently using `adb shell am startservice com.srini.remoteshopservice/.RemoteShopKeyService -n com.srini.remoteshopservice.action.FOO` . Printing the action still gets me android.intent.action.MAIN

Comment: **update**: of course it should be `-a`, not `-n`, sorry for typo

Comment: But isn't -a applicable only to activities? is it applicable to services?

Comment: it is applicable to `Intent`s, did it work or not?

Comment: I'm sorry I lost net connection during my train ride. No it did not work. I got an error saying no activity found.

Comment: what activity? you are using `am startservice ` not `am start`...

Comment: whoops. yes you're right. Thanks. Got it :)